# Strange query results

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem. I found somewhere queries like these:

```
SELECT name, surname FROM person WHERE name LIKE '[b-g]%'
SELECT name, surname FROM person WHERE name LIKE '[bcd]%'
SELECT name, surname FROM person WHERE name LIKE '[^b-g]%'
```

And I tried it by myself:

```
select name from person where name like '%[^gkl]%'
select * from person where surname like '%[r-z]%'
```

I tried to separate chars with comma

```
select * from person where surname not like "%[n,j,e,a]%" and name not like "P%"
```

But all I get are empty tables or all records from table person, like there were no conditions. I did it through phpmyadmin from XAMPP, pasted queries into console (also from XAMPP) and still got nothing expected. So I'm curious if this is actually not working or I made mistake somewhere in queries. Thanks for any helpful links or explanations "Why it's working like that?". If anything is unclear I'll try to fix it as soon as I get up.
Table looks like:

```
create table person (ID int not null auto_increment, surname varchar(100) 
collate utf8_general_ci, name varchar(100) collate utf8_general_ci, primary 
key(ID)) engine = innodb character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: I agreed with Gordon ans @daniel1490  check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69aa9 and play with different where a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, the wildcards for `like` are exactly:

- `%` to represent any number of characters
- `_` to represent exactly one character

That's it.  Based on your question, you probably think that SQL `like` supports ranges of characters and other regular-expression like patterns.  But it doesn't.

You are probably confused because SQL Server happens to support ranges of characters.  You are not using SQL Server (given away by the auto increment).  MySQL has regular expression support, so you can do:

```
WHERE name REGEXP '^[b-g]'
```

There are many resources for learning about regular expressions on the web.